# How to retrieve every records based on dropdownlist without gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

how to retrieve all records based on dropdownlist in ASP.NET C# without gridview?

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    btnArquivo.OnClientClick = "document.getElementById('" + fuAnexo.ClientID + "').click(); return false;";
    txtAnexo.Attributes.Add("onclick", "document.getElementById('" + fuAnexo.ClientID + "').click(); return false;");
    fuAnexo.Attributes.Add("onchange", "document.getElementById('" + txtAnexo.ClientID + "').value = this.value;");
}
}

protected void ddlAula_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gvQuestoes.DataSource = Questao.CarregarPorAula(Int32.Parse(ddlAula.SelectedValue));
    gvQuestoes.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask].

Comment: Are you facing any issue ?

Comment: Your title says **without** `Gridview` but you are using a Gridview in your code.

Comment: You meant to show gridview values based on dropdown selected value?